# Can we merge two data frames along Rows, at every nth position?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, row

Dataframe 1

| **INDEX | MATHS | SCORE** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Student1 | 44 |
| 2. | Student2 | 35 |
| 3. | Student3 | 36 |

Dataframe 2

| **INDEX | SUBJECT | SCORE** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | English | 50 |
| 2. | Science | 37 |
| 1. | English | 36 |
| 2. | Science | 44 |

Required Dataframe:

| **INDEX | SUBJECT | SCORE** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | English | 50 |
| 2. | Science | 37 |
| 3. | Maths | 44 |
| 1. | English | 36 |
| 2. | Science | 44 |
| 3. | Maths | 35 |
| 1. | English | 47 |
| 2. | Science | 30 |
| 3. | Maths | 36 |

The need is to merge Dataframe 1 into Dataframe 2, as every 3rd row.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mix between long and wide formats. The best would be to have all the tables in the long format.

```py
math = pd.DataFrame(
    {
     'math': ['Student1', 'Student2', 'Student3'],
     'score': [44, 35, 36]
    }
)

other = pd.DataFrame(
    {
     'student_id': 2*['Student1', 'Student2', "Student3"],
     'subject': 3*['english', 'science'],
     'score': [50, 37, 36, 44, 47, 30]
    }
)
```

The `other` df is

|  | student_id | subject | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Student1 | english | 50 |
| 1 | Student2 | science | 37 |
| 2 | Student3 | english | 36 |
| 3 | Student1 | science | 44 |
| 4 | Student2 | english | 47 |
| 5 | Student3 | science | 30 |

and the `math` df is

|  | math | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Student1 | 44 |
| 1 | Student2 | 35 |
| 2 | Student3 | 36 |

## Long Format

```py
# for the long format
math['subject']="math"
math = math.rename(columns={'math': 'student_id'})
```

|  | student_id | score | subject |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Student1 | 44 | math |
| 1 | Student2 | 35 | math |
| 2 | Student3 | 36 | math |

```py
other.append(math).sort_values(['subject', 'student_id'])
```

|  | student_id | subject | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Student1 | english | 50 |
| 4 | Student2 | english | 47 |
| 2 | Student3 | english | 36 |
| 0 | Student1 | math | 44 |
| 1 | Student2 | math | 35 |
| 2 | Student3 | math | 36 |
| 3 | Student1 | science | 44 |
| 1 | Student2 | science | 37 |
| 5 | Student3 | science | 30 |

## Wide Format

```py
# the key to merge dfs is student_id
math_wide = math.rename(columns={'math': 'student_id', 'score': 'math'})
math_wide
```

|  | student_id | math |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Student1 | 44 |
| 1 | Student2 | 35 |
| 2 | Student3 | 36 |

```py
other_wide = other.pivot(index='student_id', columns="subject", values='score').reset_index()
other_wide = other_wide.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
all_subject = other_wide.merge(math_wide, on='student_id')
```

|  | student_id | english | science | math |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Student1 | 50 | 44 | 44 |
| 1 | Student2 | 47 | 37 | 35 |
| 2 | Student3 | 36 | 30 | 36 |